# How to set the background image using Sass

Tags: css, sass

I tried setting my background image this way:

```
body
  font: 100% $font-stack
  background: url(images/body-bg.png) repeat #181d25
```

But it is showing an error, i.e. invalid. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are there any semicolons in your sass?

Answer (score 0):

Is the images folder a subdirectory of your css folder? If it is a sibling of your css folder you have to move up the file tree.

```
background: url("../images/body-bg.png") repeat #181d25;
```